# Create GraphQL connection between User and Role Type via Role and query them

Tags: graphql, schema, resolver

I want to create a GraphQL connection between **User** <> **Role** <> **Role_Type** and finally get the User Role Type back with a query. Here is brake it down to the only important lines of code:

```
type Query {
  getUsers: [User]
}
type User {
  _id: ID
  firstname: String
  roles: [Role]
}
type Role {
  _id: ID
  role_type_id: ID
  role_types: [Role_Type]
  user_id: ID
}
type Role_Type {
  _id: ID
  name: String
}
```

and in the User resolver I have:

```
Query: {
  getUser: async (root, { _id }) => {
    return prepare(await DBUsers.findOne(ObjectId(_id)))
  }
},
User: {
  roles: async ({_id}) => {
    return (await MongoDBRoles.find({user_id: _id}).toArray()).map(prepare)
  }
}
```

and for the Role resolver:

```
Role: {
  role_types: async ({_id}) => {
    return (await MongoDBRoleTypes.find({role_type_id: _id}).toArray()).map(prepare)
  },
},
```

When I query now with:

```
{
  getUser(_id: "5d555adcd2c22a242863f7a1") {
    firstname
    roles {
      _id
      role_type_id
      user_id
      role_types {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": {
      "firstname": "Gregor",
      "roles": [
        {
          "_id": "5d90cf352f50882ab0ce3877",
          "role_type_id": "5d90ce48b7893d19bcc328f9",
          "user_id": "5d555adcd2c22a242863f7a1",
          "role_types": []
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But why is `role_types` empty. As you can see the `role_type_id` is filled. So why there is no connection.

When I watch into MongoDB I can see the Role Type of the user.[image: MongoDB]

If you need more Schema/Resolver let me know.

Comment: It's unclear from just the above how the different fields are related, but I assume based on what you said that the `role_types` are related to each `Role` according to its `role_type_id`. If that's the case, your resolver isn't matching on that field -- you're using the Role's `_id` instead.

Comment: Thanks. So you say to change the `role_types: async ({_id}) => {
      return (await MongoDBRoleTypes.find({role_type_id: _id}).toArray()).map(prepare)
  },` by replacing the `_id`? But for me that looks right.

Comment: Btw I tested your idea with `role_types: async ({role_type_id}) => {
      return (await DBRoleTypes.find({_id: role_type_id}).toArray()).map(prepare)
    },`it does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was kind of easy to fix. Actually the **Role resolver** was going multiple matches. But somehow it needs to be single lookup. That does not make much sense but somehow the search for the id lookup is a single lookup. Anyway here is what I have changed and now it works properly.

Replace this:

```
role_types: async ({_id}) => {
  return (await MongoDBRoleTypes.find({role_type_id: _id}).toArray()).map(prepare)
},
```

with:

```
role_type: async ({role_type_id}) => {
  return prepare(await DBRoleTypes.findOne(ObjectId(role_type_id)))
},
```

and you fix this.